# How to run desktop shortcut using window service background worker C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, backgroundworker

I have application shortcut in desktop. I need to run that shortcut every one hour using windows service in c#. Is this possible?

Comment: Thats why they invented the Windows Task Scheduler, _http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task_

Comment: Answer is **yes**. You should create a Windows Service, Use `Process.Start()` to start the program defined in the shortcut.

Comment: process.start() is not working.. Process.Start(@"Desktop\Screen.lnk");

Comment: 'Program **defined in** the shortcut'. What is the advantage of 'running' a shortcut instead of the program itself?

Comment: Actually i want to lock my screen automatically every one hour using windows service. so i have used the bellow code in background worker. but its not working. Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe", "user32.dll,LockWorkStation");

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather not start any external processes for locking your workstation. You can lock your workstation by calling: *(not tested)*

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

Call it with:

```
LockWorkStation();
```

Source: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.lockworkstation

Comment: This is also i have used but not working in win service.

Comment: Thats probably because it runs under a different user. (You might try the checkbox 'interact with desktop')